# Sherlock's silly side

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Sometimes Sherlock can be a total weirdo when I'm in the room with him.
>
> "HorSesHoe sheLlsHocks remOrsEless cOmmerceLess chRomosOmes," he said to me. "CocKLEShells!" I replied, whereupon he smiled and walked away.

What in the world just happened?

*This puzzle (I use the term loosely) can stand entirely on its own, but for context, I'm having a bit of fun with [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94130/holmes-scrambled). With @Krishna's blessing of course; I'll take it down if desired.*

Comment: Are we to assume that both of you can hear capitalisation in spoken text?

Comment: @Bass That was supposed to create a little bit of ambiguity, but the answer is no, Sherlock and I wouldn't hear that. The letters are capitalized for another reason.